# PHP statement within echo

Tags: php, echo, file-get-contents

I am essentially trying to combine to PHP statements.

```
<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>
<?php echo file_get_contents( "../css/themes/subtitle.php"); ?>
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents( "ROOT_PATH/css/themes/subtitle.php"); ?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: LOL how can I call the ROOT_PATH from within the the file_get_contents function? I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: check my answer. don't call constants inside single or double quotes.

Comment: Keep it separate like ROOT_PATH."/css/themes/subtitle.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple you can change it to following

```
//full path of the file 
$file_name = ROOT_PATH."/css/themes/subtitle.php";
echo file_get_contents($file_name);
```

it should work

Answer (score 2):

If you call constants inside single or double quotes then it will be always picked as a string.

You need to add like below:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents( ROOT_PATH."/css/themes/subtitle.php"); ?>
```

Comment: That looks like what I am after, but it isn't working.

Comment: Check first ROOT_PATH is having correct path. Try like echo ROOT_PATH; die;

Comment: You correctly defined ROOT_PATH or not and correct path must be there. You can print your complete path first to check if it is correct or not.

Comment: I can confirm ROOT_PATH is working, for example both of the two statements I posted produce the results I expect.

Comment: ROOT_PATH must be having ".." only then the path will be like ../css/themes/subtitle.php

Comment: I am new to PHP, obviously. But I am well familiar with UNIX file paths and I experimented with a few variations. I'm not sure why I couldn't get this to work but I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`.` operator is used to concatenating.

Like:

```
$str = "Hello";
echo $str;
echo "World";
```

can be written as

```
$str = "Hello";
echo $str."World";
```

Comment: I can see that your answer is essentially what Mahesh Hegde did in the answer that I marked as correct. As I am new to PHP I couldn't really look at what you posted and see the result I was after. I'm not there yet. But thanks for taking the time to post.

Comment: I gave you the general solution which is also applicable to your question.